# Determine if 2D-projected point is visible

Tags: directx, direct2d

I render a model and do have various 3D points around the surface of it. Because it's easier and I'm already using D2D for UI rendering, I implemented it so that these points are rendered as 2D points onto the screen.

The thing is that of course not all points are always visible. I'd like to test that and only show these which are actually seen by the camera.

Is there any way besides rendering them in Direct3D or reading the depth-buffer CPU-side to test it?

Comment: You could raycast the point back to the camera to see if it intersects with anything in the scene though that might even be less performant depending on how complex your model is.

Comment: I got about 400k vertices, so I guess that would be a hell of a bottleneck... I got informed about a hacky solution, rendering the scene color-encoded whereas the color represents the face or object's ID. Might be a way to go. But it'd be cool if I could kinda raycast...

Comment: Lol, sounds exactly like my old project. Using a lower poly model for raycasting really helped with things like this. I've seen that way done in as well and it works surprisingly well but you'll reach an upper limit of colors you can have if you need to ID something over the max number of colors you can store.